# C++ - swprintf_s doesn't output to buffer in console

Tags: c++, console, buffer

I'm writing a console game in C++ and I'd like to be able to do menus easily. The screen state is stored in a wchar_t* screen[screenWidth*screenHeight]. I wrote a class Menu that should write to my screenbuffer to display a scoreboard. The class has a draw function that takes a pointer to the screenbuffer and some coordinate parameters. The draw function uses swprintf_s to change the state of the screenbuffer, however when I run the code it doesn't output anything. I tried changing the swprintf_s call by passing in a literal but it still doesn't work. However when I just use raw swprintf_s from main() it works.

```
void Menu::draw(wchar_t* screen, int xScreen, int yScreen, int xField, int yField,
int xMenu, int yMenu) {
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); ++i) {
    int currentY = yMenu / (buttons.size() + 1) * (i + 1);

    swprintf_s(&screen[xScreen * currentY + xField + xMenu / 2 - 7], 16, buttons[i].str);
}
```

}

buttons is a vector of menus, str is a wchar_t* to the menu's text.
When I just use the function in main:`swprintf_s(&screen[15 * nScreenWidth + nFieldWidth + 6], 16, L"SCORE: %8d", nScore);`
outputs as it should. Any suggestions?